# What is this catepillar/slug in my garden?

Tags: identification, caterpillar, slugs

There's like 50 of them crawling around, I'm not sure if I should be concerned? Seemingly happened overnight.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: These may be army worms from their look but I am not sure.

Comment: If they are all climbing up your walls, they are probably looking for somewhere safe to pupate. Whatever damage they did to your plants has already been done. (Note: Wikipedia says army worms pupate underground...)

Comment: what part of the world are you located in?

Comment: i am in east texas